# property self.representedObject not initialized at super.init call

Tags: ios, swift, customview, mapbox

Пишу кастомный коллаут для карты в моем приложении. Вью для коллаута загружаю из xib файла. Карта работает на фреймворке MapBox. Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть переменная representedObject которая является MGLAnnotation. MGLAnnotation не имеет инициализаторов, nil быть не может. Когда моя вью начинает инициализироватся выскакивает ошибка:

```
property self.representedObject not initialized at super.init call
```

В этом инициализаторе:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Переменная representedObject объявлена так:

```
var representedObject: MGLAnnotation
```

Опциональной она быть не может, протокол MGLCalloutView требует именно такого объявления. Получается замкнутый круг - сделать ее опциональной не могу, присвоить nil не могу, инициализировать не могу. Какие предложения? Вот код целиком:

```
import Foundation
import Mapbox

class CustomCalloutView: UIView, MGLCalloutView {


@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var infoButton: UIButton!

var textLabelText: String {
    get {
        return textLabel.text!
    }
    set(textLabelText) {
        textLabel.text = textLabelText
    }
}

var view: UIView!
var nibName: String = "CustomCalloutView"

var representedObject: MGLAnnotation
var leftAccessoryView = UIView()/* unused */
var rightAccessoryView = UIView()/* unused */
var delegate: MGLCalloutViewDelegate?

required init(representedObject: MGLAnnotation) {
    self.representedObject = representedObject
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

func loadFromNib() -> UIView {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    return view
}

func presentCallout(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, constrainedTo constrainedView: UIView, animated: Bool) {
    if !representedObject.responds(to: #selector(getter: UIPreviewActionItem.title)) {
        return
    }
    let view = loadFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    view.addSubview(self)
    if isCalloutTappable() {
        // Handle taps and eventually try to send them to the delegate (usually the map view)
        infoButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CustomCalloutView.calloutTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    } else {
        // Disable tapping and highlighting
        infoButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    if animated {
        alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) { [weak self] in
            self?.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}

func dismissCallout(animated: Bool) {
    if (superview != nil) {
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { [weak self] in
                self?.alpha = 0
                }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        } else {
            removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}

func isCalloutTappable() -> Bool {
    if let delegate = delegate {
        if delegate.responds(to: #selector(MGLCalloutViewDelegate.calloutViewShouldHighlight)) {
            return delegate.calloutViewShouldHighlight!(self)
        }
    }
    return false
}

func calloutTapped() {
    if isCalloutTappable() && delegate!.responds(to: #selector(MGLCalloutViewDelegate.calloutViewTapped)) {
        delegate!.calloutViewTapped!(self)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему разбив данный класс на 2, в первый приходит запрос на отрисовку коллаута, он запрашивает у второго загрузить вьюху из xib, второй класс ее загружает и отдает первому, и первый уже работает с вьюхой